# Elasticsearch - Using terms and bool at same time in filtered query gives error

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch

I'm building query for search, but got stuck on searching for multiple values for one field (location). Such that, it can be more than one city.
My query looks like:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "filter" : {
                "terms" : { 
                    "location" : [Baku, Paris, London]
                },
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result is 400: SearchPhaseExecutionException ... QueryParsingException

What can be the reason?

Terms documentation I used: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `terms` filter must be located inside the `bool/must` clause, like below. And don't forget to surround your city names with double quotes as well.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "terms": {
                "location": [ "Baku", "Paris", "London" ]
              }
            },
            ...
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: and now it doesn't give an error, but returns 0 response. Adding directly in must => term (without 's') gives result. But it doesn't allow search for multiple values.

Comment: Hard to tell without seing some sample data. Feel free to share some as well as the mapping you're using.

Comment: The number 1 reason for getting zero results is not being aware of analysis. If the field `location` is analyzed, then you should get zero results as `terms` filter does not analyze the terms you are trying to match. Just try to execute the query again with the names of the locations in all small letters and if results are returned, it will confirm my hypothesis. In any case, `mapping` is the source of truth.

Comment: Thanks @bittusarkar . What about having multiple terms query like, cities, districts? Like searching for one district in Paris and entire London.

Comment: I did not get your question exactly, so I would recommend creating another question with all the details present (especially the mapping of your index).